# Extracting a number from a specific substring pattern

Tags: c#, regex, linq

**SOLVED**! Ended up using this to do what I wanted:

```
if (output.Contains("<%TABLE#"))
    {
         string pattern = @"<%TABLE#([0-9]+)%%>";
         RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

         foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(output, pattern, options))
         {
               int objectID = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(m.Value, @"\d+").Value);
               output = output.Replace(m.Value, ConvertFunction(objectID));
         }
    }
```

In some parts of my SQL data (rendered by a C#/ASP.NET website front-end) are strings, many of which can contain a pattern like <%TABLE#[NUMBER]%%> - [NUMBER] is always a specific ID, 1+. An example in one string would look like <%TABLE#3%%>. Sometimes there may be more than one of these patterns in the same string. I am ultimately trying to do the following:

1. Find all instances in the string where the pattern occurs
2. For each instance, call another building function using the # that is present - it takes that # and produces a NewString
3. Replace that instance of the code with NewString

I do this because each of the SQL tables has a website page to show the data within to the end-user. The way I format the data differs from table to table, so I have a Class for each table that builds the output string and returns it where needed. Sometimes, I need to display an object from a different table within the current one. To try and solve this, I added the above formula within the string, in the specific spot I want the object to be rendered, in the hopes of identifying it and using the ID within to grab the appropriate object, build it, then replace that pattern.

I'm guessing I'll have to use Regex or something to identify the string, but I'm struggling on the best way to grab the pattern, identify the number within, call the function to render the output text using said number, and then replace that specific pattern with the results.

Below are some example inputs and what the output should be. The function ConvertFormula takes in an INT and outputs a STRING.

**EXAMPLE INPUTS/EXPECTED OUTPUT**

Example 1:
`"Here's some data and more stuff.<%TABLE#3541%%>Here is more text. 
<%TABLE#31214%%>And some more."`

Output 1:
`"Here's some data and more stuff." + ConvertFormula(3541) + "Here is more text." + ConvertFormula(31214) + "And some more."`

Example 2:
`"Here's some data and more stuff! Maybe more here!<%TABLE#2%%>Here is more text."`

Output 2:
`"Here's some data and more stuff! Maybe more here!" + ConvertFormula(2) + "Here is more text."`

Example 3:
`"<%TABLE#2%%>This is something completely different with the object call at the start.<TABLE#52%%> and another here."`

Output 3:
`ConvertFormula(2) + "This is something completely different with the object call at the start." + ConvertFormula(52) + " and another here."`

Example 4:
`"There's nothing in this one, no code to find. Just has some text."`

Output 4:
`"There's nothing in this one, no code to find. Just has some text."`

Example 5:
`"This one goes on for a while, like 5132854123 characters, then has a single call right here.<%TABLE#112%%>"`

Output 5:
`"This one goes on for a while, like 5132854123 characters, then has a single call right here." + ConvertFormula(112)`

Example 6:
`"Short <%TABLE#412%%> one."`

Output 6:
`"Short " + ConvertFormula(412) + " one."`

Example 7:
`"Nothing here again."`

Output 7:
`"Nothing here again."`

Comment: Edited it again - about as clear as I can make the examples. Showed exactly what input/output should be for each. ConvertFormula logic isn't critical, it just takes an INT and returns a STRING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that this expression might simply work,

```
<%TABLE#([0-9]+)%%>
```

which we would use a capturing group and collect our desired IDs.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GDmbu2/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"<%TABLE#([0-9]+)%%>";
        string input = @"<%TABLE#3%%>
<%TABLE#1213%%>";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This ended up being very helpful! I used it to figure out the solution, editing my initial post now to show it.